# Generating a Cartesian Map with Python that can be implemented in a browser (?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, browser, cartesian-coordinates

I need to display a map with Cartesian coordinates for a little game that I'm writing in Python. My main issue: it is required to implement this game and its display map in a browser. Implementing `pygame` in a browser seems to be problematic however and since the map itself is just for updating moves and locations (not interactive itself) I have no need for `pygame`.

I have absolutely no experience in implementing a browser game by any means whatsoever. Any sound advice regarding this matter would be appreciated a lot.

The specific question: how do I generate a Cartesian map with Python that can be browser implemented? It is also required that I can layer the map with a more attractive image. Can I use `matplotlib` for example?

Comment: Look into the "webagg" backend for matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_webagg.html

Comment: browser displays HTML, images and SVG (and it can use CSS and JavaScript) so your code have to generate image (PNG, JPG, etc.), SVG or HTML. Bo you would need also Web Server - so yo would need rather web framework like flask, bootle, django and some module to generate image like PIL/pillow.